# Add active class to nav created from globals

Tags: navigation

I have a simple nav set up using Globals in a table, but I'm struggling to get it to add an active class to only the active page.

The below code adds the nav links, but I need to know what to add to it to get the active class on only the current page.

Need a little help please?

```
{% if mainNav.navitems|length %}
    {% for row in mainNav.navitems %}
        <li><a href="{{ row.url }}">{{ row.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[image: Main Nav]

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your URL structure ultimately and whether you have sub pages, but I think the easiest way to do it would be something like:

```
{% if mainNav.navitems|length %}
 {% for row in mainNav.navitems %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ url(row.url) }}"
     {%- if craft.request.segment(1) == row.url %}class="active"{%- endif %}>
     {{ row.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You don't have to use the `segment(1)` method if it doesn't suit, take a look at [the request docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request) to find something that suits your URLs

Comment: Thanks alec, I managed to solve it just before you answered. But in your one the active class would be added to the <a> tag, so wouldn't work as needs to go on the <li>

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it `{% if row.url == craft.request.firstSegment %}class="active" {% endif %}`

Here's the full code.

```
{% if mainNav.navitems|length %}
{% for row in mainNav.navitems %}
  <li {% if row.url == craft.request.firstSegment %}class="active" {% endif %}><a href="{{ row.url }}">{{ row.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```